# Android Studio - Exception locking surface cannot be caught

Tags: java, android, exception, canvas, android-studio

Hi I made a game in Android Studio.  Occasionally when I close and restart the application on the emulator I get the following spammed into logcat:

```
Exception locking surface
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Surface was already locked
```

I tried surrounding `canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();` with a try-catch block but the exception is not being caught.  is there a way I could check if the canvas is locked before attempting to lock it?

Here is my code in the MainThread.java class

```
    while (running) {
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        canvas = null;

    try {
     canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                // update game state
                this.gamePanel.update();
                // draws the canvas on the panel
                this.gamePanel.draw(canvas);
            }

        } catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}finally {
            // in case of an exception the surface is not left in
            // an inconsistent state
            if (canvas != null) {
                try {

                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

                }
                catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            }
    }
```

Comment: Have you found the answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

You can identify and use a boolean constant for checking;

```
    //create the boolean;
private boolean cLocked = false;


//Locking
 if (!cLocked){
    canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
    cLocked = true;
}

//Unlocking
if (cLocked) {
    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    cLocked = false;
}
```

This will prevent the exception. It will not lock when it is already locked and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This helped me with a similar issue. I was getting the same Exception.

Comment: Seems to work for me.  I wasn't getting this exception until I ran my game on Ice Cream Sandwich (SDK level 15).

Comment: I must point out that in Android Studio, the query on cLocked (the second one) is saying it's always true.  I don't see how that is.  I'm locking the canvas in a try/catch block, where I don't lock it without seeing if it's not locked first (with the boolean).  I have a finally block that unlocks the canvas, but only if the canvas is not null and not locked.  That's where it's saying it (the boolean) is always true.  That can't be the case if there's a caught exception and cLocked wasn't set to true.  Any ideas?